# Follow process with htop

Tags: htop

I'm using htop to monitor processes, whenever I want to find a running process I the `/` command which highlights the process until it moves on the list. Is there a way to keep the selected process highlighted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read `man htop`, especially the `INTERACTIVE COMMANDS` part:

```
  F    "Follow" process: if the sort order causes the currently selected process to move in the list, make the selection bar follow it. This is useful for monitoring a process: this
        way, you can keep a process always visible on screen. When a movement key is used, "follow" loses effect.
```

After you `/`, `F`

Comment: this is not working for me Ubuntu 20.04 lts.  the cursor just moves anyway.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @JonGrah you to highlight the process, then press `F`. If you just press `/`, you will enter search mode and type the `F` letter in the search bar at the bottom. You need to finish your search by pressing `Return` ("Enter") before pressing `F`